# Doppler broadening: time scale to frequency scale

Tags: spectroscopy

[image]
 Consider a cell containing Rubidium and enlight it with a laser. Connect the system with an oscilloscope and give a triangular wave as input (so you can know when the Rubidium is resonant). This is the signal that you see downward. You can see the output in the upper signal. It is given by the difference between input signal and the signal received by the photodiode... Looking at the spectral line relative to D2 rubidium transition, the oscilloscope gives me this picture.

I need a pragmatic hint. I have to measure the Doppler broadening so I need to convert time scale to frequency scale.

How can I do that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: A more detailed escription of what we're looking at would be nice. As it stands you goive us no clues what the oscilloscope screen is portraying.

Comment: @JohnRennie updated question!

Comment: What is the triangular signal controlling? The frequency of the laser? If so what is the range of frequencies you're using?